# Find all Equiangular Platonic triangles

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry, noneuclidean-geometry

A spherical triangle A is called equiangular if its 3 angles are equal. A is called Platonic if copies of A tile the unit sphere. I need to find all such triangles. Don't we have an infinite amount of them? Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: I figured that since an equiangular triangle has equal angles, by Girard's Theorem, we have that the area of the triangle is 3a - pi. Since we're looking for equiangular triangles that tile the sphere, we obviously need a finite number of these spherical triangles to tile the sphere. Also the surface area of the sphere is 4pi, therefore we can write for some finite n: (3a - pi)n = 4pi, and we can now use the fact that the sum of the angles in the triangle is between pi and 3pi. i.e 3a is between pi and 3pi, which implies that a is between pi/3 and pi. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

There are three Platonic solids that have equilateral triangles as faces: the tetrahedron, the octahedron, and the icosahedron. All these bodies can be circumscribed by spheres. On the circumscribing spheres we can naturally define the spherical triangles corresponding to the faces of the cirumscribed solids. There cannot be other regular coverings of the sphere because then there would be other Platonic bodies.

The task is to calculate the spherical angles of the generated spherical triangles.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you just wrote. What do you mean by: 'we can naturally define the spherical triangles corresponding to the faces of the cirumscribed solids' ? How do the equilateral triangles making up say, the tetrahedron, correspond to a different spherical triangle than the equilateral triangles of the octahedron?

Comment: @John.P: The vertices of a platonic body are points of the surface on the circumscribing sphere. An edge of the solid connects the vertices AB. These points are on the surface of the sphere. The spherical segment connecting AB is the corresponding edge on the sphere.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now. In my course though, we've not covered Platonic solids and circumscribed spheres, so I don't think this method is the one my teacher is looking for. Are there any other methods you could guide me through? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't havy any other idea. Wiki explains the Platonic bodies...

Comment: Could you tag in other mathmos you know who can be helpful? Thanks!

Comment: So how do I find the number of combinations of the 3 angles from each of the 3 solid platonic bodies?

Answer (score 0):

As a warning to other potential posters this is a current homework problem:

http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/Teach/2015_MA243/examples6.pdf

Which coincides with the timing of your post.
So any posters should refrain from posting full solutions as of yet.

**HINT**

To aid intuition, first consider the tessellation of the plane by some p-gons and try to derive an equation on the total angle sum about any point where the vertices of these p-gons meet.
There are similarities between this and the tiling of the sphere.